# Booting from USB sends me to Grub rescue mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.10 and I followed the instructions [here](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) perfectly and I used the BIOS to boot from my USB (F12, InsydeH20) and after a few seconds, it sended me to Grub rescue mode. Whenever I boot from my HDD, Ubuntu boots fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you put the `grub.cfg` file in the right place? Did you install GRUB in the `boot` folder of USB drive? Do you get any errors when installing GRUB?

Comment: I created the folder grub then made a grub.cfg file and saved it in there. I think I did something wrong because I found a folder on my desktop with the other grub files. I copied those files to the boot/grub folder. There were no errors when installing grub.

Comment: the 'grub' folder should already be on the USB drive after a correct installation procedure. When you run 'grub-install' be sure you are using the correct paths, specifically the USB drive mount path.

Comment: The path I entered was media/<my_name>/windows/boot/grub. I found a folder that said media on my desktop. I forgot to enter / before media. That might have been the problem.

Comment: The '/' is mandatory. And replace <my_name> with your username.

Comment: I will add / next time. Thank you (and <my_name> was an example, I put my username)

Comment: Just repeat the grub installation step, there is no need to copy Windows files again to USB.